# System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, system.text.json

I am working a asp.net core project with Postgresql.

I wrote a query to get a list `ArrivalGuide` .

```
// this is working fine
var x = await _catalogDbContext.Destinations.ToListAsync();  

// But I got error for this query
var y = await _catalogDbContext.ArrivalGuide.ToListAsync();
```

I got this error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Techne.TravelHub.Data.CatalogDbContext'.
>
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $[9].PointsOfInterests[3].Meta[9].Content | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 103060.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.
>
> at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()
> at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnRead(ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& readStack, Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at Npgsql.TypeHandlers.JsonHandler.Read[T](NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 byteLen, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)

Entity classes:

```
public class ArrivalGuide
{
     public List<DestinationSection> Sections { get; set; }
     // removed rest
}

public class DestinationSection
{
    public List<PointsOfInterest> PointsOfInterests { get; set; }
    // removed rest
}

public class PointsOfInterest
{
    public List<PointOfInterestMeta> Meta { get; set; }
}

public class PointOfInterestMeta
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
builder.Property(i => i.Sections)
            .HasColumnType("jsonb");
    
builder.Ignore(i => i.Video);
```

Why does this error occur?

**Edit:** sections - jsonb

```
[
  {
    "Iso": "eating",
    "PointsOfInterests": [
      {
        "Meta": [
          {
            "Type": "address",
            "Content": "1A Bailuzhou Dong Lu, Siming District, Xiamen"
          },
          {
            "Type": "phone",
            "Content": "+86 592 5330 888"
          },
          {
            "Type": "www",
            "Content": null
          },
          {
            "Type": "openinghours",
            "Content": "11h - 14h30, 17h - 22h30"
          }
        ],
        "Description": "S",
        "IsAdvertisement": false
      },
      {
        "Meta": [
          {
            "Type": "address",
            "Content": "515 Siming Nan Lu, Siming District, Xiamen"
          },
          {
            "Type": "phone",
            "Content": "+86 592 2085 908"
          },
          {
            "Type": "www",
            "Content": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**BUT I really don't want to select sections. I need only Iso, Image, Description, video**

`var arrivalGuideList = await _techneDbContext.ArrivalGuide .Select(x => new { x.Iso, x.Image, x.Description, x.Video }).ToListAsync();`

But I got same error. Why I got the above mentioned error fro this query too. I did not select `sections`.
Then why this error occurs?

`System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $[9].PointsOfInterests[3].Meta[9].Content | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 103060.`

Comment: seems the error is data related, the query is returning some unexpected value from database that cannot be cast to the entity

Comment: The error is caused by json deserialize error.  `Sections` is type of jsonb, could you pls share the value in database?

Comment: Error states that the JSON value stored for `$[9].PointsOfInterests[3].Meta[9].Content` cannot be deserialized as a string.  So, what does your raw JSON look like?  We need to see the JSON to diagnose the problem further.  If you don't know, try changing `Content` to `JsonElement` and find out.  Or deserialize the entire thing to `JsonElement` to dump the entire raw JSON.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late reply.
I have edited the question with `Sections`. Please help me to find the mistake

Comment: I can deserialize the JSON shown in your question to a `List<DestinationSection>` successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/veu2V9.  Are you sure this really is a [mcve]?  *`Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.`* suggests that you have some JSON that looks like `"Content": { /* Some object properties here */ }`

Comment: Okay Thank you, I will check. 
BUT I really don't want to select `sections`.
I need ` var arrivalGuideList = await _techneDbContext.ArrivalGuide
                            .Select(x => new { x.Iso, x.Image, x.Description, x.Video }).ToListAsync();`  
But same error.

Comment: I really don't want to select sections. I need only Iso, Image, Description, video
`var arrivalGuideList = await _techneDbContext.ArrivalGuide
                            .Select(x => new { x.Iso, x.Image, x.Description, x.Video }).ToListAsync();`  

But I got same error. Why I got the above mentioned error for this query. I did not select `sections` in the above query. Then why this error occurs?